# Create a property dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I have an Structure in a Class where i have a property named 'Name'. and other properties values inside the structure depends of the set of this value, is there any way to make them publics only when this first property is Set ?.

When i create an instance of the class , and access to this structure all the properties are available.

Comment: No, it is not possible to *change* the visibility of class properties at run time. Why do you want to do this? There are other ways of implementing *restriction mechanisms* for example you could use enumeration (states like unset, set) or default values.

Comment: Sounds like you need to make them public read, private write. And does it need to be a struct? With a string in it, I'm not sure if you need that.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it has to be inside the 'structure', because i have other structures inside this Class. i wonder even if there is a way of create this properties dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hook up these properties with an `ICommand` implementation.

For each property that depends on `Name`, they can use `CanExecute` to determine if `Name` is set. If so, `CanExecute` will return true, and the Command will be executed for the property (which can hook up to a method to do anything you want...get a value, set a value, etc.)

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)